# Where are the faction quartermasters?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Along with the addition of a new island in Mists of Pandaria, a variety of new factions have also been added;

- Anglers
- August Celestials
- Brewmasters
- Cloud Serpents
- Golden Lotus
- Klaxxi
- Lorewalkers
- Shado-Pan
- Tillers
- Wrathion (The Dark Prince)

Do all of the above factions actually have a quartermaster? If so, where are the faction quartermasters located for each of these new factions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the list:

**Anglers**

- Quartermaster - [Nat Pagle](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=63721)

**August Celestials**

- Horde Quartermaster - [Sage Lotusbloom](http://www.wowdb.com/npcs/64001-sage-lotusbloom)
- Alliance Quartermaster - [Sage Whiteheart](http://www.wowdb.com/npcs/64032-sage-whiteheart)

**Brewmasters**

- Quartermaster - Teng Thundermalt (could not find a link). Located right outside the Stormstout Brewery in the Valley of The Four Winds.

**Cloud Serpents**

- Quartermaster - [San Redscale](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=58414)

**Golden Lotus**

- Quartermaster - [Jaluu the Generous](http://www.wowdb.com/npcs/59908-jaluu-the-generous)

**Klaxxi**

- Quartermaster - [Ambersmith Zikk](http://www.wowdb.com/npcs/64599-ambersmith-zikk)

**Lorewalkers**

- Quartermaster - [Tan Shin Taio](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=64605)

**Shado-Pan**

- Quartermaster - [Rushi the Fox](http://www.wowdb.com/npcs/64595-rushi-the-fox)

**Tillers**

- Quartermaster - [Gina Mudclaw](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=58706)

Sources: [MMOChampion](http://www.mmo-champion.com/content/2829-Faction-Quartermasters-Character-Creation-Screen-Blue-Posts-GW2-Release-Date), [WoWDB](http://www.wowdb.com/items) via Item look ups, [WoWJuju](http://www.wowjuju.com/_/wowarticles/mop-factions-quick-preview-and-quartemasters-l-r209).

Comment: Turns out Wrathion is not a faction, but the NPC responsible for the legendary quest. I'm sure his faction (The Dark Prince) will not actually have a quartermaster

Comment: I don't think it is since it's not even listed inside the list of factions on WoWJuju. For now I'm going to remove my Wrathion/Dark Prince portion from my answer.